# JQuery Input[Name=""] not getting recognized on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have a JavaScript code that reads the content of an html textbox and is working on IE and Chrome but is not being recognized by Firefox.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="SetInner_Form">                
    <form name="Set_Password" method="post" action="">
        Email Address &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input class="Auth" name="SetPwd_Username" type="text"/><br/><br/>
        New Password   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="Auth" name="SetPwd_NewPwd" type="password"/><br/><br/>
        Retype Password &nbsp;<input class="Auth" name="SetPwd_RetypePwd" type="password"/><br/><br/>
        <div id="SetPwdResultWrapper">
            <div id="SetPwdResult" class="Validation_2"></div><br/>
        </div>
        <div id="RedirectLink" align="center" class="NoDisplay">Click <a href='https://localhost/webapp/index.aspx'>here</a> to go to main page</div><br/>
    </form>
    <div id="SetPwdBtnWrapper">
        <input id="SetPwdBtn" name="SetPwdBtn" type="submit" value="Confirm" align="center"/>
    </div>
    <img id="LoadingIcon_auth"/>
</div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
$("input[name=SetPwd_Username]").val()
```

Exception (on Firefox console):

```
Uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=SetPwd_Username
```

JQuery version is: jquery-1.6.4.min.js

The weird part is, Firefox can recognize the other html elements except for the `SetPwd_Username`

Am I missing something?

Comment: yes you missed the part where the value is string and requires you to put in single quotes

Comment: Are you trying to read it `something = $(...).val()` or assign a value `$(...).val(something)` ?

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/496rc/1/

Comment: I am reading a value on something.  I already found the culprit (as stated by cookie monster), I missed the closing ].

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Based on your error message, you forgot the closing `]` in the selector.

This:

```
"input[name=SetPwd_Username"
```

would not be valid, and produces that exact error message.

---

Chrome does not give an error for the invalid selector. It seems that its `.querySelectorAll()` implementation doesn't reject it as it should. That's the reason for the difference.

Because Firefox correctly rejects the selector, it defaults to the Sizzle engine, which then throws the error. Since Chrome doesn't reject it, you don't get the error.

Comment: This finding worked for me! I did missed to include the closing bracket.  Follow-up question, is there a tool out there that can let me verify or check these corrections?  Because I am only using notepad++ as my javascript editor.

Comment: You mean malformed selectors? Not that I'm aware of, other than looking for error messages in the console.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the name of the field in single quotes.

```
$("input[name='SetPwd_Username']").val()
              ^ here          ^ and here
```

Comment: This isn't a requirement. It's perfectly valid without the quotes.

Comment: @cookiemonster I suppose that!

Comment: This should work with or without the quotes. Docs say it can be an unquoted single word or a quoted string. http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: @Masterbuddha I think in cases like this, it is better to be consistent and always include the single quotes

Comment: @jasonscript I agree, I tend to always use quotes for attribute selectors.

Comment: Quotes actually matter when using something like `input[name^='group[something]']`

Answer (score -1):

You must notice : have a diffirence between css and jquery, that is sysmbon "'"
in jquery

```
 $("input[name='SetPwd_Username']")
```

and in css

```
input[name=SetPwd_Username]{
}
```